# What limits supersaturation in the absence of nucleation sites?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solubility, vapor-pressure, gas-phase-chemistry

Imagine a scenario where we have a chamber with air that is supersaturated with water vapour. In this ideal scenario there are no nucleation sites (e.g no suspended particles or nucleation on the walls of the chamber).

What is the physical/chemical mechanism that limits further supersaturation?

Comment: The wall of the chamber will serve as a nucleation site. If you magically make that impossible, then I guess you may get insanely high supersaturation, before molecular fluctuations in the air will become new nucleation sites.

Comment: There is still ionization due cosmic rays and natural ( mostly radon ) radioactivity, which serves as nucleation centre source. It was used earlier as detector of energetic charged particles.

Comment: Okay, since it's a hypothetical scenario, we forbid also those. Basically the question then is if there exists a mechanism that enforces an upper limit or not (e.g. as pointed out by @Ivan Neretin molecular fluctuations)?

Comment: There are **many** such mechanisms; you turn one off, then another steps in. It is pretty much like death.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - now, you just have to prevent the molecules from interacting with each other. Sounds easy to me...

Comment: @JonCuster Why, of course, that would mean turning water into an ideal gas, so no more phase change whatsoever. It is pretty much like heaven or hell.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Do you have a source for the "insanely high" supersaturation that one could reach? It is rather simple to make a perfectly clean experiment, dust-free  and deionised, and natural radioctivity is easily excluded, because you can *see* it when it occurs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber

Comment: @Karl - things like drop towers and fast pulse-laser melting can easily reach 100's of K of supercooling of liquids below the melting temperature.

Comment: @JonCuster That I know, the records for supercooled water are falling faster than one can keep up with them. But supercooling gets *increasingly (sic) easier*, as everything slows down, supersaturation does not advantage itself like that.